# Fastest way to get exact count of rows for a 100GB CSV file stored on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, duckdb

What is the fastest way of getting an exact count of rows for a 100GB CSV file stored on [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) without using [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) nor any [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) or [EC2 VM](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)? I can't use Athena, because the CSV file isn't clean-enough for it. I can't use Fargates or EC2 VMs, because I need a purely serverless solution. I can't use third-party services like [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/en/) (native AWS services only).

Also, 100GB is too large to fit within a [Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html)'s `/tmp` (limited to 10GB). I could try to run something like [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/) (or any other streaming database engine) on a Lambda and scan the entire file with a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "s3://myBucket/myFile.csv"` query, but the Lambda is quite likely to timeout, because its read bandwidth from S3 is 100MB/s at best, and it cannot run for more than 15 minutes (900s).

I know the approximate size of the file.

**Note**: I have an inaccurate estimate of the number of rows provided by [AWS Glue Data Catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/components-overview.html)'s crawler, with an error margin of -50%/+100%. This could be used for some kind of iterative or dichotomous process, but I could not figure any out. For example, I tried adding an `OFFSET` with a value lower than but close to the number of rows to the aforementioned query, but the Lambda running DuckDB timed out. That was disappointing and somewhat surprising, because a query like `SELECT * FROM "s3://myBucket/myFile.csv" LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10000000` worked well.

Comment: S3 lets you read a byte range, so you can invoke parallel Lambdas and add up their results.

Comment: That's exactly the solution that we're looking at right now. End of lines for CSVs generated by Google Sheets seem to contain `\r\n`, while carriage returns embedded within cells are only `\n`. We need to try with other CSV files.

Comment: Note the advice [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-byte-range-fetches.html): "If objects are PUT using a multipart upload, it’s a good practice to GET them in the same part sizes (or at least aligned to part boundaries) for best performance. GET requests can directly address individual parts; for example, GET ?partNumber=N". So, assuming you have control over how the original file is uploaded, you might benefit from controlling the part size.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is probably to use [`SelectObjectContent`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_SelectObjectContent.html) with `ScanRange` to parallelize the request on chunks of 50MB or so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "AWS S3 select":https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html. It lets you run queries on S3 files. I use the service to get basic insight into any file on S3(Provided it can be queried).

Comment: Yes. Same as `SelectObjectContent`, as mentioned in other reply.